# wp_kses ignore allowed and allow everything

Tags: sanitization, wp-kses

Here is an example:

```
$allowedPart = "<a href='http://alink.com'></a>";
$unsafePart = "<h1>A title</h1>";
$unsafePart .= "<script>alert('a script!!!');</script>";

$unsafeString = $allowedPart . $unsafePart;

$allowed = array("a"=>array(
                    "href"=>array()
           ));

$sanitizedString = wp_kses($unsafeString, $allowed);
```

`$sanitizedString` should be equals to `$allowedPart`, but something goes wrong and 
`$sanitizedString` remains the same as `$unsafeString`.

What's wrong?

==========================

Sorry, after saving to the database, I did `location.reload()`, and consequently in the textarea was maintained the original content, but in database the value is **almost** correct. This secondary issue was solved using:

`window.location.href = window.location.href;`

However there is a problem, **'href' disappears too**, why?

For example

`<a href='http://alink.com'>Link</a>` 
becomes
`<a>Link</a>`

Trying something like:
`$allowed = array( 
        'img'=>array(
            'src'=>array(),
        ));`

`<img src='img.png' />` 
becomes
`<img />`

It's as if wp_kses() recognize as unallowed all the attributes in sub-array (like href or src), filtering them and their content.

==========================

Using double quotes instead of single ones seems to solve.

`$allowed = array( 
        'img'=>array(
            'src'=>array(),
        ));`

`<img src="img.png" />`

Comment: I just had the same experience, replaced single quotes with double quotes and now it works as expected. Seems buggy to me.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_kses` ([Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses)) removes unallowed tags, but it doesn't remove their content. So, if you have a `<script>{something}</script>`, `wp_kses` only removes the tags, not the content, returning `{something}`. Thus, this is intended behaviour and your issue doesn't seem to be a bug.